# Incrementing PHP Dates

Tags: php, sql, date

I am writing a part of an application where a user can add an event that spans multiple days. So I get in the post $begindate, $enddate, and $type. Type will be daily, weekly, or monthly. I'm trying to process the request for daily right now. What I need to do is do an insert into a my dates table a row for each day including the begindate, enddate, and each day in between if daily is selected. Since months have different amounts of days obviously, and I can't simply add 1 or 7 to the day part of the php date how would I approach this?

I do

```
$begindate = date('Y-m-D', strtotime($begindate))
```

for all dates when I receive the post.

I haven't worked too much with PHP date objects, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class if at all possible. Then, check out [DateTime::add()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).

Also, the [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) class can automatically create a series of DateTime objects at the interval that you request, which will make it a lot easier to accept different recurrence intervals:

```
$start = new \DateTime($beginDate);
$end = new \DateTime($endDate);
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new \DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $day) {
    // will iterate over each day in the period
}
```

DateTime is really quite flexible in the strings it accepts in its constructor (check out the reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)), which makes it pretty trivial to get dates from today. For example, if you want a DateTime object that represents one week from right now, `$date = new \DateTime('+1 week');` will do that for you.

Comment: awesome, worked flawlessly. I've never used DatePeriod before, very cool. Thanks for the help. Why the \'s before the DateTime object declaration?

Comment: When namespace support was added to PHP in 5.3, trying to call the DateTime class from your own class that also uses namespaces will throw an error, because it will look for the DateTime class in your namespace (more about namespace resolution [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php)). The preceeding slash just tells PHP to look in the global namespaces. If you're not using them (or are using a PHP version that doesn't support them), just leave them off.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Yea I am on 5.3 so it worked fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
$days = 1; // Or 7 or 30, or anything..
$nextday = date('Y-m-D', strtotime($begindate) + 86400 * $days);
```

Or use `DateTime` object.

```
$days = 1; // Or again 7.. or 30..

$begin = new DateTime($begindate);
$begin->add(new DateInterval('P' . $days . 'D'));
$nextday = $date->format('Y-m-D');
```

If you need to add extra weeks or months check [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) for details.